# Comparing closures in Python

Tags: python, closures

My goal is to compare two bounded closures and check if they are bounded with the same input argument `len`

```
def foo(len: int):
    def foob():
        return len
    return foob

a = foo(1)
b = foo(1)
print(a == b)
```

The output is False.
But when I check for equality using the following,

```
print(a.__closure__ == b.__closure__)
```

the output appears to be True and False when the input argument `len` is different (just as I want it to work). The problem comes when I am traversing through a large dictionary of such function closure signature where `__eq__` is checked for instead of `__closure__`. Is there any way to get around this?

**UPDATE:** There was a lack of clarity in the problem.
If I were to do something like this:

```
a_dict[foo(1)] = 0x12
```

It would create a new closure object for foo(1) even if foo(1) were present in the dictionary as it checks using `__eq__` method.

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is *exactly*.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Basically, foo(1) == foo(1) should return `True` and foo(1) == foo(2) should return `False`. This is not the case for closure objects

Comment: *"The problem comes [in code I'm not showing]"*.

Comment: It really seems like functions with closures are not the best choice. Might be better to use a class for this. Another option would be to store them in a subclass of dict that understands what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, terminology note. `foo(1)` returns a **function object**. That *function object creates a closure*. It is not a "closure object". This was sort of confusing because it wasn't clear what you were referring to. In any case, *all function objects* use identity for equality comparisons, most mutable objects will do that by default.